# Get dynamic json form data in angular

Tags: angular14, angular16

The below image for create custom fields in angular. IF I clicked dropdown option it should dispaying one text box with add more option button. Then clicking add more button it will displaying another text box. Those two text box for dropdown options.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYxZG.jpg)

HTML code :

```
<form [formGroup]="forms">
                <div class="w-12">
                    <div class="gap-2">
                        <label htmlFor="username">Label</label>
                        <input pInputText aria-describedby="username-help" class="w-full" />
                        
                    </div>
                  
                </div>
                <div class="w-6">
                    
                    <div class="gap-3">
                        <div *ngFor="let category of categories" class="field-checkbox">
                            <p-radioButton [inputId]="category.key" (ngModelChange)="getFieldsType(category.key)" name="category.key" [value]="category" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory"></p-radioButton>
                            <label [for]="category.key" class="ml-2">{{ category.name }}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="w-12">
                        <div class="gap-2" *ngIf="textbox">
                            <label htmlFor="username">Label</label>
                            <input pInputText aria-describedby="username-help" class="w-full" />
                            
                        </div>
                        <form [formGroup]="addDropdown">
                            <div class="gap-2" *ngIf="dropdown">
                                <div formArrayName="fieldArray">
                                <div *ngFor="let field of getPhonesFormControls(); let i = index">
                                <input pInputText formControlName="i" aria-describedby="username-help" class="w-full" />
                                <!-- <button (click)="removePhone(i)">Remove Phone</button>     -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <a href="javascript:;" (click)="addPhone()">+ Add Option</a>
                            </div>

                            
                        </form>
                        <a href="javascript:;" (click)="getformfields()">Save</a>
                    </div>
                   
                </div>
            </form>
```

Typescript code :

```
export class AddEditComponent {

     visible : boolean = false;
     selectedCategory: any = null;
     textbox: boolean = false;
     dropdown : boolean = false;
     addDropdown !: FormGroup;
     forms !: FormGroup;
     fieldArray :any = [];
     categories: any[] = [
         { name: 'Textbox', key: 'A' },
         { name: 'Dropdown', key: 'M' },
         { name: 'Radio', key: 'P' },
         { name: 'Checkbos', key: 'R' }
      ];

      // formFieldsJson : any;
 
      constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private router: Router,
        ) {
          this.addDropdown = this.fb.group({
            // fieldArray: this.fb.array([])
            fields: this.fb.array([
               this.fb.control('')
            ])
         })
        }

       addPhone(): void {
         (this.addDropdown.get('fields') as FormArray).push(
           this.fb.control('')
         );
       }
  
         getformfields() {
          const formjson = this.addDropdown.value;
          console.log(formjson)
        }
        getPhonesFormControls(): AbstractControl[] {
          return (<FormArray> this.addDropdown.get('fields')).controls
        }
        getFieldsType(key:any) {
           console.log(key);
           if(key === 'A') {
             this.textbox = true;
             this.dropdown = false;
           }
           else if(key === 'M') {
              this.dropdown = true;
              this.textbox = false;
            }
   
         }

           addField() {
            const fieldControl = this.fb.control(''); // Create a new FormControl
            this.fieldArray.push(fieldControl); // Add the FormControl to the FormArray
           }
    }
```

My output become like  :

```
fields = [
          {
          type: "dropdown",
          label: "gender",
          name: "gender",
          options: [
             {
               label: "male",
               value: "male",
             },
             {
               label: "female",
               value: "female",
             }
           ]
          }
        ]
```